# Как проверить работу блокировок (lock tables) в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть необходимость проверить, существует ли запись с определенными данными в таблице.

Затем в php, в зависимости от результата, записывать данные в другую таблицу, либо в эту же.

Таким образом делаю следующее:

1. В php-скрипте создал подключение к БД.
2. Лочу таблицы

   ```
   LOCK TABLES `table1` WRITE, `table2` WRITE
   ```
3. Делаю выборку и все необходимые дейтствия.
4. Делаю анлок

   ```
   UNLOCK TABLES
   ```
5. Закрываю соединение с БД.

Как я могу проверить работоспособность лока?

У меня было два варианта:

1. Убрать из php-скрипта анлок и закрытие соединения. Запустить скрипт два раза подряд. Думал, что второй раз выборка не сработает из-за первого лока, но почему то сработала. Могу предположить, что из-за того, что, раз в скрипте сначала выполняется лок таблиц, то, запуская второй раз скрипт, я отменяю предыдущую блокировку (т.к. повторный лок убирает все предыдущие локи), но, с другой стороны, в начале скрипта создается новое соединение к БД, и из-за нового лока не должно происходить анлока.
2. Убрать из php скрипта анлок и закрытие соединения. Запустить скрипт. Выполнить запрос к таблице в phphMyAdmin. Здесь тоже все прошло успешно, т.е. запрос выполнился, несмотря на блокировку. Быть может sql такой умный и сам анлочит таблицу?

Где гарантия, что лок/анлок все таки работает? Как проверить это? Быть может, тип таблицы влияет на работу блокировки, или еще что-то?

Comment: а скрипт, где вы блокировку делаете, перед повторным запуском уже отработал? или дальше работает? и зачем такие сложности? Есть же транзакции, он блокировки сама делает. Если innodb, то не на уровне таблицы, а на уровне строк, что намного лучше будет

Comment: скрипт к этому времени уже отрабатывает, но мне казалось, что это не должно влиять, т.к. анлок не делаю и соединение не закрываю, разве что дело в соединении, если оно само закрывается, после выполнения скрипта. Про транзакции особо не читал, в теории знал про блокировки, поэтому их и реализовывал. Спасибо, почитаю про них. В других скриптах использовал begin-commit, но здесь такой вариант не очень подходит, т.к. в зависимости от результатов первого запроса выполняется пачка других.

Comment: "скрипт завершил работу" почти всегда равно "соединение с базой закрыто", а раз закрыли соединение, то другие соединения могут работать дальше. "Проверить" можно - в вашем скрипте после LOCK TABLES делаете паузу на 20 секунд и за это время запускаете второй скрипт - он будет ждать пока первый скрипт не отработает. И не совсем понятно чем именно btgin/commit не подходит. Все же запросы можно в одной транзакции выполнить, а значит доступ у запросов будет к одним и тем же данным

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, теперь понял в чем была проблема в моих опытах :) По поводу транзакция, я вероятно что-то не так понял, изучу этот момент более детально. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @BOPOH Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.